# How to combine php send mail forms with a list of image click?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, email

I'm creating 4 button on a webpage for a building entrance. I'm using 'awesome menu' as the page layout like the demo http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/css-menu/demo/demo.html

So each menu button is clicked, an email is sent to an appropriate department automatically.  Eg Ninja button is clicked, an email is sent to ninja@example.com

I've got my php form I'm thinking of using to send emails, my question is that how can combine my php form with this menu list code? I'm a bit lost so any help is appreciated.

Here is my code for the page layout, an image is attached to each button using css like the [awesome menu](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/css-menu/demo/demo.html) demo download code.

```
<body>
<ul id="awesome-menu">
<li><a href="#ninja" class="ninja">Ninja</a></li>
<li><a href="#zombie" class="zombie">Zombie</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

And here is the php form code I'm thinking of using to send emails

```
<form action="" method="post">  //for first list
<input type="submit" value="Send details" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_a" value="1" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['button_a']))
{
$to      = 'ninja@example.com';
$subject = 'You have a visitor';
$message = 'hello I am here to see ninja';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@site.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@site.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'Email Sent A.';
}
?>


//for second list 
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Send details to b" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_b" value="1" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['button_b']))
{
$to      = 'zombie@example.com';
$subject = 'You have a visitor';
$message = 'hello I am here to see zombie';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@site.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@site.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'Email Sent.';
}
?>
```

Comment: ninja or zombie, where do you live, im not visiting your neighbourhood :-)

Comment: So basically you want the links in the list to send an email and then redirect to the corresponding page?

Comment: Hi @Mike, Yes that is exactly what I'm after, all my pages are on one page using a photo slider, so after sending the email it will go to the next div, how can I target the links in the list sending email part please? Thanks very much. Hi Dagon, haha, that just came with the menu. Any thoughts on how can I do it? Thanks, S:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<ul id="awesome-menu">
<li>
    <form action="emailAndRedirect.php" id="ninja" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="ninja" />
     </form>
     <a href="javascript:void" onclick="formSubmit('ninja')" class="ninja">Ninja</a>
</li>
<li>
    <form action="emailAndRedirect.php" id="ninja" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="zombie" />
     </form>
     <a href="javascript:void" onclick="formSubmit('zombie')" class="zombie">Zombie</a>
</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit(name)
    {
          if (name == 'ninja') {
              document.getElementById("ninja").submit();
          } else if (name == 'zombie') {
              document.getElementById("zombie").submit();
          }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in your php:

```
<?php

$url = //url of the page you wan t

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if ($name == 'ninja') {
        $email = 'ninja@example.com';
    } else if ($name == 'zombie') {
        $email = 'zombie@example.com';
    }
}
$to      = $email;
$subject = 'You have a visitor';
$message = 'hello I am here to see $name';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@site.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@site.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: $url#$name');
?>
```

Edit: Thjs uses javascript, so you would be reliant on it. With a javascript form submit function you would be able to keep the same links and styling and still submit the forms.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply. Is there any way I can put the a tag <a href="#ninja" class="ninja"> in? I need it to go to the next div, also I need it to make the hover affection of the page. Thanks, S

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the following ups, do i need to change anything from the code you wrote above? The email is not getting sent through for some reason. Also where shall I put the next div link when the email is sent? Sorry I'm fairly new to php, your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks, S:)

Comment: You probably would, for example, what is the name of the php script you are using to send the email? (as in the file name)

Comment: The php code in my question was in the body when I was still developing the site, after your suggestion, I have put the php code into a file called emailAndRedirect.php like you named it. I tried your code but the email is not getting sent for some reason. Any thoughts on that? Sorry Mike I have to go for an hour but will keep in touch. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You also need to specify the url variable in the php script. Where do you want the script to redirect to? I made a few edits to the code and tested it on my machine. It should be working.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks very much for all your help. Everything is working apart from the php part. When I used your php above, I didn't receive any emails when the button is clicked, but if I use the original php which I wrote in my post, I received emails with your html and javascript code no problem, but of course there are duplicated php code there. Any chance you could have a look at the php part of yours, why it doesn't receive email? Thanks very much. S:)

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry to bother you again, I'm having some issue to make your javascript and my photoslide script to work together, I'm just wondering if you could help me, sorry i'm a bit slow. I've got 3 divs on one page #item1, 2 & 3, so each div is clicked, the next div should show up like a photoslide. With your code for the buttons, I can either send the email or slide the page depending on where i place the a tag in the list. I posted a new question if you could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405183/button-submit-email-and-photoslide-are-not-working-together